# Log use of files in a particular directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging, filesystems

I'm cleaning up an absolute mess of files - and have 75 gig of files which I'm not sure if they're being accessed through apache (and if they are, they're likely behind a maze of redirects) - I've duplicated the files, but with a new structure as the old structure was not coping with so many sub-folders.

What I would like to do, is log ONLY access to files beyond a certain path on the file-system /home/httpd/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/hugedirectory/ so I can see if it's safe to delete them and recover some space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple.  Use `grep` on your log file to filter out everything except the directory you're interested in.

```
grep 'GET /hugedirectory/' /var/log/apache2/sitename.access.log
```

Apache doesn't have a good way to separately log requests beyond the `VirtualHost` level.  If you really want to have apache log directly to a separate log file, you could accomplish that with a custom logging script and pipe apache's access log to it.  The `CustomLog` directive can specify a program which apache will start and write log data to that program's stdin, where you could then do some basic parsing and write the log files yourself.

Seriously though, just use `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is probably to enable logging in Apache, then filter the logs for the path. Not as elegant as only logging for some files, but probably simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to parse-through your apache logs, looking for entries that match the base path (`/var/www/html/hugedir` may be `/hugedir` in the logs).

If after some amount of time (determinable by you, of course), you see no matches, it should be safe.